# Add attribute based on Node name (incremental) in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to add an ID attribute to every node that has a child element, based on the node name but increment the reference if one already exist.  While I can add the attributes, I am unsure how to increment them based on previous occurrences.  Any help in this would be greatly appreciated

Initial xml

```
<xml>
    <individual>
        <name>
            <firstname>Me</firstname>
            <lastname>Last</lastname>
        </name>
        <addresses>
            <address>
                <street>1234 Main</street>
                <city>Anytown</city>
                <state>TX</state>
            </address>
            <address>
                <street>4321 Central Ave</street>
                <city>Bixby</city>
                <state>ND</state>
            </address>
        </addresses>
        <employeers>
            <employeer>
                <name>
                    <firstname>Employer1</firstname>
                    <lastname>EmployerLast</lastname>
                </name>
                <addresses>
                    <address>
                        <street>1234 Employer1</street>
                        <city>Smallville</city>
                        <state>CT</state>
                    </address>
                </addresses>
            </employeer>
            <employeer>
                <name>
                    <firstname>Employer2</firstname>
                    <lastname>EmployerLast2</lastname>
                </name>
                <addresses>
                    <address>
                        <street>1234 Employer2</street>
                        <city>Nashville</city>
                        <state>TN</state>
                    </address>
                </addresses>
            </employeer>
        </employeers>
    </individual>
</xml>
```

Desired result

```
<xml>
    <individual ID="indivdual_1">
        <name ID="name_1">
            <firstname>Me</firstname>
            <lastname>Last</lastname>
        </name>
        <addresses ID="addresses_1">
            <address ID="address_1">
                <street>1234 Main</street>
                <city>Anytown</city>
                <state>TX</state>
            </address>
            <address ID="address_2">
                <street>4321 Central Ave</street>
                <city>Bixby</city>
                <state>ND</state>
            </address>
        </addresses>
        <employeers ID="employeers_1">
            <employeer ID="employeer_1">
                <name ID="name_2">
                    <firstname>Employer1</firstname>
                    <lastname>EmployerLast</lastname>
                </name>
                <addresses ID="addresses_2">
                    <address ID="address_3">
                        <street>1234 Employer1</street>
                        <city>Smallville</city>
                        <state>CT</state>
                    </address>
                </addresses>
            </employeer>
            <employeer ID="employeer_2">
                <name ID="name_3">
                    <firstname>Employer2</firstname>
                    <lastname>EmployerLast2</lastname>
                </name>
                <addresses ID="addresses_3">
                    <address ID="address_4">
                        <street>1234 Employer2</street>
                        <city>Nashville</city>
                        <state>TN</state>
                    </address>
                </addresses>
            </employeer>
        </employeers>
    </individual>
</xml>
```

I found the following code to count occurrences of a specific element, but am unsure how to apply the count to a specific node.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:variable name="newline">
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:key name="elements" match="*" use="name()"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    <xsl:text>Summary of Elements</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    <xsl:for-each 
      select="//*[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('elements',name())[1])]">
      <xsl:sort select="name()"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="key('elements', name())">
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
          <xsl:text>Element </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
          <xsl:text> occurs </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="count(//*[name()=name(current())])"/>
          <xsl:text> times.</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
    <xsl:text>There are </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(//*)"/>
    <xsl:text> elements in all.</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a job for `xsl:number`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*//*[*]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:attribute name="ID"><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>_<xsl:number level="any"/></xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWV1, it transforms the input you have posted into the output

```
<xml>
    <individual ID="individual_1">
        <name ID="name_1">
            <firstname>Me</firstname>
            <lastname>Last</lastname>
        </name>
        <addresses ID="addresses_1">
            <address ID="address_1">
                <street>1234 Main</street>
                <city>Anytown</city>
                <state>TX</state>
            </address>
            <address ID="address_2">
                <street>4321 Central Ave</street>
                <city>Bixby</city>
                <state>ND</state>
            </address>
        </addresses>
        <employeers ID="employeers_1">
            <employeer ID="employeer_1">
                <name ID="name_2">
                    <firstname>Employer1</firstname>
                    <lastname>EmployerLast</lastname>
                </name>
                <addresses ID="addresses_2">
                    <address ID="address_3">
                        <street>1234 Employer1</street>
                        <city>Smallville</city>
                        <state>CT</state>
                    </address>
                </addresses>
            </employeer>
            <employeer ID="employeer_2">
                <name ID="name_3">
                    <firstname>Employer2</firstname>
                    <lastname>EmployerLast2</lastname>
                </name>
                <addresses ID="addresses_3">
                    <address ID="address_4">
                        <street>1234 Employer2</street>
                        <city>Nashville</city>
                        <state>TN</state>
                    </address>
                </addresses>
            </employeer>
        </employeers>
    </individual>
</xml>
```

Comment: This is a better solution than what I'd suggested.  +1

Comment: Wow...this is simple yet effective...I would have pulled my hair out trying to figure this out...Thank you

Comment: Is it possible using xsl:number to get the count of the parent node or the node, when looping through attributes?  I updated the code based on my thoughts, but it does not appear to work as desired.  http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv89/1.

Comment: Consider to ask a new question for a new problem, showing and explaining in the post which result you want to achieve.

Comment: it is the same topic, but at a parent node or attribute level

Comment: If the current answer to your previous problem does not allow you to solve the new problem then you need to ask a new question and explain what you want to achieve, I am not going to try to infer from "it does not appear to work as desired" what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is creating replacement templates with global counts for each element.
This means six templates for the given set: `name`, `individual`, `address`, `addresses`, `employeers`, `employeer`.

Each of these templates match with `//` to get the global count in the variable `idx`. Then they replace the current node with a copy and add the new `ID` attribute. The *identity template* copies all other nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity template -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- global templates for specific element 'name' -->
<xsl:template match="//name">
  <xsl:variable name="idx" select="count(preceding::name) + 1" />
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="ID"><xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(),'_',$idx)" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- global templates for specific element 'address' -->
<xsl:template match="//address">
  <xsl:variable name="idx" select="count(preceding::address) + 1" />
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="ID"><xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(),'_',$idx)" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- global templates for specific element 'addresses' -->
<xsl:template match="//addresses">
  <xsl:variable name="idx" select="count(preceding::addresses) + 1" />
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="ID"><xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(),'_',$idx)" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- global templates for specific element 'individual' -->
<xsl:template match="//individual">
  <xsl:variable name="idx" select="count(preceding::individual) + 1" />
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="ID"><xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(),'_',$idx)" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- global templates for specific element 'employeers' -->
<xsl:template match="//employeers">
  <xsl:variable name="idx" select="count(preceding::employeers) + 1" />
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="ID"><xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(),'_',$idx)" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- global templates for specific element 'employeer' -->
<xsl:template match="//employeer">
  <xsl:variable name="idx" select="count(preceding::employeer) + 1" />
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="ID"><xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(),'_',$idx)" /></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is an XSLT-1.0 solution and the output should be as desired.