# Xsl:number for parent and attribute nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Previous post - [Add attribute based on Node name (incremental) in xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47896527/add-attribute-based-on-node-name-incremental-in-xsl/47904095)

Thanks to Martin, I am working through a subsequent project based on the same code.  In this project, I need to be able to increment the parent nodes to create a somewhat relational xml output based on the original.  I also need to create relationships for attributes as they relate to the current node.

Summary of desired results

- List all nodes as  - completed
- a) List all parent nodes as an ID field for child relationships -
  completed
- b) List all child nodes (lowest level nodes with no children) as  - completed
- c) List all attributes as:
- i) if no child node is present  - unable to
  pull ### for parent node
- ii) if child node is present  - unable to pull ### for parent node

Input xml:

```
<xml>
    <individual attr="test" attr2="test3" attr3="test2">
        <name>
            <firstname seq="1">Me</firstname>
            <lastname>Last</lastname>
        </name>
        <addresses>
            <address>
                <street>1234 Main</street>
                <city>Anytown</city>
                <state>TX</state>
            </address>
            <address>
                <street>4321 Central Ave</street>
                <city>Bixby</city>
                <state>ND</state>
            </address>
        </addresses>
        <employeers>
            <employeer>
                <name>
                    <firstname seq3="99">Employer1</firstname>
                    <lastname>EmployerLast</lastname>
                </name>
                <addresses>
                    <address>
                        <street>1234 Employer1</street>
                        <city>Smallville</city>
                        <state>CT</state>
                    </address>
                </addresses>
            </employeer>
            <employeer attr="test" attr2="test3" attr3="test2">
                <name>
                    <firstname>Employer2</firstname>
                    <lastname>EmployerLast2</lastname>
                </name>
                <addresses>
                    <address>
                        <street>1234 Employer2</street>
                        <city>Nashville</city>
                        <state>TN</state>
                    </address>
                </addresses>
            </employeer>
        </employeers>
    </individual>
</xml>
```

Current xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*//*[*]">
        <xsl:element name="KEY">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>_<xsl:number format="001" level="any"/>_ParentID</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>_<xsl:number format="001" level="any"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:element name="KEY">
                <!-- Trying to get the output to list:
                    1) the current node and increment - issue
                    2) the current attribute -->
                <xsl:attribute name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>_<xsl:number format="001" level="any"/>_<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:element name="KEY">
            <!-- Trying to get the output to list:
                1) the parent node and increment - issue
                2) the current node -->
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>_<xsl:number format="001" level="any"/>_<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:element name="KEY">
                <!-- Trying to get the output to list:
                    1) the parent node and increment - issue
                    2) the current node
                    3) the current attribute -->
                <xsl:attribute name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name(../..)"/>_<xsl:number format="001" level="any"/>_<xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>_<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Code test location - http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv89/2

Actual versus Desired Results:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<KEY name="individual_001_ParentID" value="xml_001" />
<KEY name="individual_001_attr" value="test" />
<KEY name="individual_001_attr2" value="test3" />
<KEY name="individual_001_attr3" value="test2" />
<KEY name="name_001_ParentID" value="individual_001" />
<KEY name="name_001_firstname" value="Me" />
<KEY name="name_001_firstname_seq" value="1" />
<KEY name="name_001_lastname" value="Last" />
<KEY name="addresses_001_ParentID" value="individual_001" />
<KEY name="address_001_ParentID" value="addresses_001" />
<KEY name="address_001_street" value="1234 Main" />
<KEY name="address_001_city" value="Anytown" />
<KEY name="address_001_state" value="TX" />
<KEY name="address_002_ParentID" value="addresses_002" />
<KEY name="address_002_street" value="4321 Central Ave" />
<KEY name="address_002_city" value="Bixby" />
<KEY name="address_002_state" value="ND" />
<KEY name="employeers_001_ParentID" value="individual_001" />
<KEY name="employeer_001_ParentID" value="employeers_001" />
<KEY name="name_002_ParentID" value="employeer_002" />
<KEY name="name_002_firstname" value="Employer1" />
<!-- actual result -->
<KEY name="name_001_firstname_seq3" value="99" />
<!-- desired result as this is the secod occurrance of the parent node-->
<KEY name="name_002_firstname_seq3" value="99" />
<KEY name="name_002_lastname" value="EmployerLast" />
<KEY name="addresses_002_ParentID" value="employeer_002" />
<KEY name="address_003_ParentID" value="addresses_003" />
<KEY name="address_003_street" value="1234 Employer1" />
<KEY name="address_003_city" value="Smallville" />
<KEY name="address_003_state" value="CT" />
<KEY name="employeer_002_ParentID" value="employeers_002" />
<!-- actual result -->
<KEY name="employeer_001_attr" value="test" />
<KEY name="employeer_001_attr2" value="test3" />
<KEY name="employeer_001_attr3" value="test2" />
<!-- desired result as this is the secod occurrance of the parent node-->
<KEY name="employeer_002_attr" value="test" />
<KEY name="employeer_002_attr2" value="test3" />
<KEY name="employeer_002_attr3" value="test2" />
<KEY name="name_003_ParentID" value="employeer_003" />
<KEY name="name_003_firstname" value="Employer2" />
<KEY name="name_003_lastname" value="EmployerLast2" />
<KEY name="addresses_003_ParentID" value="employeer_003" />
<KEY name="address_004_ParentID" value="addresses_004" />
<KEY name="address_004_street" value="1234 Employer2" />
<KEY name="address_004_city" value="Nashville" />
<KEY name="address_004_state" value="TN" />
```

Comment: Consider adding the desired output to your question.

Comment: added actual versus desired results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be able to simplify the stylesheet a little by capturing the name/number in a variable and passing it as a parameter in the apply-templates.

You should also be able to use a single template for all attributes and elements with no child elements.

There also doesn't seem to be a reason to use `xsl:element` instead of creating literal result elements.

I've used `local-name()` throughout. If you need to include any namespace prefixes, use `name()` instead.

I've also used XSLT 2.0 since that's the version specified in your stylesheet. In the example links below I changed the engine to Saxon-HE instead of MS XslCompiledTransform (which is a 1.0 processor).

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*" priority="1">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="parentInfo"/>
    <xsl:variable name="nbr">
      <xsl:number format="000" level="any"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="parentNbr">
      <xsl:number format="000" level="any" select=".."/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <KEY
      name="{string-join((local-name(),$nbr,'ParentID'),'_')}"
      value="{string-join((local-name(..),$parentNbr),'_')}"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,*">
      <xsl:with-param name="parentInfo" 
        select="string-join((local-name(),$nbr),'_')"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|*[not(*)]">
    <xsl:param name="parentInfo"/>
    <KEY
      name="{string-join((
      if (self::attribute() and not(../../*[*])) then 
      ($parentInfo,local-name(..)) else $parentInfo,
      local-name()),'_')}"
      value="{.}"
    />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*">
      <xsl:with-param name="parentInfo" select="$parentInfo"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<KEY name="individual_001_ParentID" value="xml_001"/>
<KEY name="individual_001_attr" value="test"/>
<KEY name="individual_001_attr2" value="test3"/>
<KEY name="individual_001_attr3" value="test2"/>
<KEY name="name_001_ParentID" value="individual_001"/>
<KEY name="name_001_firstname" value="Me"/>
<KEY name="name_001_firstname_seq" value="1"/>
<KEY name="name_001_lastname" value="Last"/>
<KEY name="addresses_001_ParentID" value="individual_001"/>
<KEY name="address_001_ParentID" value="addresses_001"/>
<KEY name="address_001_street" value="1234 Main"/>
<KEY name="address_001_city" value="Anytown"/>
<KEY name="address_001_state" value="TX"/>
<KEY name="address_002_ParentID" value="addresses_001"/>
<KEY name="address_002_street" value="4321 Central Ave"/>
<KEY name="address_002_city" value="Bixby"/>
<KEY name="address_002_state" value="ND"/>
<KEY name="employeers_001_ParentID" value="individual_001"/>
<KEY name="employeer_001_ParentID" value="employeers_001"/>
<KEY name="name_002_ParentID" value="employeer_001"/>
<KEY name="name_002_firstname" value="Employer1"/>
<KEY name="name_002_firstname_seq3" value="99"/>
<KEY name="name_002_lastname" value="EmployerLast"/>
<KEY name="addresses_002_ParentID" value="employeer_001"/>
<KEY name="address_003_ParentID" value="addresses_002"/>
<KEY name="address_003_street" value="1234 Employer1"/>
<KEY name="address_003_city" value="Smallville"/>
<KEY name="address_003_state" value="CT"/>
<KEY name="employeer_002_ParentID" value="employeers_001"/>
<KEY name="employeer_002_attr" value="test"/>
<KEY name="employeer_002_attr2" value="test3"/>
<KEY name="employeer_002_attr3" value="test2"/>
<KEY name="name_003_ParentID" value="employeer_002"/>
<KEY name="name_003_firstname" value="Employer2"/>
<KEY name="name_003_lastname" value="EmployerLast2"/>
<KEY name="addresses_003_ParentID" value="employeer_002"/>
<KEY name="address_004_ParentID" value="addresses_003"/>
<KEY name="address_004_street" value="1234 Employer2"/>
<KEY name="address_004_city" value="Nashville"/>
<KEY name="address_004_state" value="TN"/>
```

Working examples:

- http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv89/12
- http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv89/13

Comment: Thanks for the simplification.  Now the name fields appear to work correctly, but I happen to notice that the ParentId reference for line 9 is incorrect - showing DEAL_002 when it should be DEAL_001 in version http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv89/9.  In looking back I also noticed lines 22 and 34 reference the ### for the current node rather than the parent in http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv89/8.

Comment: @mike - I'll take a look and see why.

Comment: Maybe I should simply use a for-each loop and reference the parent as a variable, then use that going down the tree as it appears xsl:number may not be able to evaluate the occurrence of a parent node.  I did try select=".." and count=".." with no success.

Comment: It looks like I was using the current numberinstead of the parent number. I added a variable to capture the parent number. Take a look and see if this fixes the issue. (The results do seem to be quite a bit different than the desired results listed in your question.) If it does, I'll update my answer. http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv89/10 http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv89/11

Comment: That works great so far but the attributes for the root are not listed in the results.  Not a big deal as the current xslt you provided captures everything else I needed.  Thank You.

Comment: @mike - That should be an easy fix. Just change the apply-templates in the template that matches `/*` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*"/>`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: While the attributes are listed for the root, the tag is missing since there is no parent as seen in version 12

Comment: @mike - Huh? So you want the root tag listed but only if it contains attributes? (I'm just guessing since the example in your question doesn't do anything with the root element (the whole reason for the `/*` template).)

Comment: @mike - I think I see what you're saying. Take a look at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv89/14 and let me know if that's what you mean. Otherwise, maybe you should update your question with exact output examples for both input examples.

Comment: @mike - Did my update (version 14) help or are you still having issues.

Comment: it is working as designed, but I am running into a couple more scenarios where it is not as expected.  trying to document and possibly work through all before reposting again.

Comment: @mike - Ok sounds good. Marking this answer as accepted and creating a new answer for any changes would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If we save the numbering in a variable, such as

```
<xsl:variable name="first_count">
    <xsl:number format="001" level="any"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

and used that variable instead of repeating the `xsl:number`

```
<xsl:value-of select="$first_count"/>
```

we can achieve the result that you wanted. The modified style sheet is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*//*[*]">
        <xsl:variable name="first_count">
            <xsl:number format="001" level="any"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="KEY">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>_<xsl:value-of select="$first_count"/>_ParentID</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>_<xsl:value-of select="$first_count"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:element name="KEY">
                <!-- Trying to get the output to list:
                    1) the current node and increment - issue
                    2) the current attribute -->
                <xsl:attribute name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>_<xsl:value-of select="$first_count"/>_<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:variable name="second_count">
            <xsl:number format="001" level="any"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="KEY">
            <!-- Trying to get the output to list:
                1) the parent node and increment - issue
                2) the current node -->
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>_<xsl:value-of select="$second_count"/>_<xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
            <xsl:element name="KEY">
                <!-- Trying to get the output to list:
                    1) the parent node and increment - issue
                    2) the current node
                    3) the current attribute -->
                <xsl:attribute name="name">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name(../..)"/>_<xsl:value-of select="$second_count"/>_<xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>_<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

see it in action in http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv89/5.

Comment: While this worked in the limited example, it did not work in my actual data as shown in the last 4 lines here http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv89/7.  All these should be ABOUT_VERSION_002 rather than 001

Answer (score 0):

At least in XSLT 2 or 3 you could also change the numbering to e.g.

```
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>_<xsl:number format="001" select=".." level="any"/>_<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
```

to count the parent element of the attribute, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#number.

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv89/6

Comment: While this worked in the limited example, it did not work in my actual data as shown in the last 4 lines here http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv89/7.  All these should be ABOUT_VERSION_002 rather than 001